# download a large amount of files from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have lots (10 million) of files (some 20K folders, each folder with about 500 files) on an EC2 EBS drive of 1TB.

I'f like to download it to my PC, how would I do that most efficiently.

Currently I'm using rsync, but it's taking AGES (about 3MB/s, when my ISP is 10MB/s).

Maybe I should use some tool to send it to S3 and then download it from there?
How would I do that, while preserving the directory structure?

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way would be to get a disc/drive sent there and back. Even today, for large sizes (>= 1 TB), snail mail is the fastest & most efficient way to send data back and forth

- http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

Answer (score -1):

S3 and parallel HTTP downloads can help, but you can also use other download acceleration tools directly from your EC2 instance, such as [Tsunami UDP](http://tsunami-udp.sourceforge.net/) or [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/)